# how can i use checkboxes which gets value from database in a loop?

Tags: database, loops, checkbox, lua

I have a table in database.In that table , there is an unknown number of rows.I want to put 
checkboxes but number of checkboxes should be equal to the Number of rows. Thus i tried to do it in while loop. I found number of rows which exists in table.It's rowNumber.Then , i did a while loop.At this point , there is a serial failure. Because when i clicked any checkbox , the row below is called with last m value.

```
 cbox[m] = checkBox.new(checkX, txtY, sendRows[m], col,
```

Because after exiting while loop , m equals rowNumber. And when any checkboxes is clicked , it doesn't know which row is clicked because m = rowNumber. I tried many things but i can't do it. What should i do ?? Should i give up using loop? IF i give up using it how can do it?

Here is the code which i can't fixed

```
local m = 1
while(m<rowNumber)

cbox[m] = checkBox.new(checkX, txtY, sendRows[m], col,
    function(this)
        local state = this:getCheck()
        if state then 
            print(m .. " checked")
            gonder[m] = 1
        else 
            print(m  .. " does not checked")
            gonder[m] = 0
        end
    end
)
screen:addChild(cbox[m])
cbox[m]:setCheck(settings.getMusicState())
txtY = txtY + gap
print ("gonder[m] = " .. gonder[m])
end
```

If the code is written as in the below,it runs correctly:

```
cbox[1] = checkBox.new(checkX, txtY, sendRows[1], col,
    function(this)
        local state = this:getCheck()
        if state then 
            print(1.. " checked")
            gonder[1] = 1
        else 
            print(1  .. " does not checked")
            gonder[1] = 0
        end
    end
)
screen:addChild(cbox[1])
cbox[1]:setCheck(settings.getMusicState())
txtY = txtY + gap

cbox[2] = checkBox.new(checkX, txtY, sendRows[2], col,
    function(this)
        local state = this:getCheck()
        if state then 
            print(2.. " checked")
            gonder[2] = 1
        else 
            print(2  .. " does not checked")
            gonder[2] = 0
        end
    end
)
screen:addChild(cbox[2])
cbox[2]:setCheck(settings.getMusicState())
txtY = txtY + gap
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved after changing the inside of while as this:

```
while( m<rowNumber + 1)
        do
            cbox[m] = checkBox.new(checkX, txtY, sendRows[m], col,
                function(this)
                end
            )
            screen:addChild(cbox[m])
                txtY = txtY + gap
                m = m + 1
        end
```

And the important point is here. Here , we are sending what we want:

```
submitt:addEventListener("click",
        function()
            local mydata={}
            local i=1
            while (i<rowNumber+1) do
                mydata[3*i-2]=cbox[i].checked--1. Holds whether it is true or false
                mydata[3*i-1]=sendRows2[i]
                mydata[3*i] = sendURL[i]
                i=i+1
            end
            sceneManager:changeScene("results", 1, SceneManager.flipWithFade, easing.outBack,mydata)
            stage:removeChild(submitt)--after clicked , the button disappears
        end)
```